# Set Android toolbar title appearance programmatically

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-actionbar

I have an Android toolbar that I have created like such within a Xamarin Forms project:

```
var toolbar = activity.LayoutInflater
   .Inflate(FormsAppCompatActivity.ToolbarResource, null)
   .JavaCast<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>();
```

I can easily set the background color and other layout parameters by doing the following:

```
toolbar.LayoutParameters = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);
toolbar.SetBackgroundColor(backgroundColor.ToAndroid());
```

However, **I can't figure out any way to programmatically set the font size** because the method to set that is:

```
toolbar.SetTitleTextAppearance(Context context, int resId)
```

And I don't want to set it with a configured resource. I want to dynamically set it with a font size and/or other style attributes. How can I do this?

Comment: Form your codes, I don't know how are you using the toolbar. Can you show your toolbar's layout? I usually use the `Toolbar` as `ViewGroup`, and I can add a `TextView` as title, then I can `findViewbyID` find the title, I can change anything I want.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is the same thing using java. When i had this problem i putted a `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` after putting the tittle in my **java** code. The result was something like this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle(loggedUserName);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Working great.

Comment: I know how to set the title string, I just don't know how to change the styling of the title.

Comment: Oh mb, try using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32398137/3681565) code