# Back button and title vertical alignment

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm using this template for the toolbar...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" >

    <TextView
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/OrangeTint"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

... and setting a custom font face on the text field in code.

```
var title = (TextView) toolbar.FindViewById(Resource.Id.toolbar_title);

    title.SetText(page.CurrentPage.Title, TextView.BufferType.Normal);

    title.SetTypeface(MainActivity.Font, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
```

Unfortunately, the back button arrow is centered about where the top of the title is.

How can I push the title up a little so that it's in alignment with the back button?

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32398104/how-to-set-a-custom-font-to-the-title-in-toolbar-android

Comment: Well I've switched to recursing over the text fields created by the system, but the alignment is still wrong.

Comment: @Ian not understanding your question, what do you need whether title need little up or back button showing at the place of title?