# How do you change the typeface of a title of a toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm making an Android App with Android Studio in Java. My app will have a toolbar. I want to change the Typeface of the title of my Toolbar to a font.

The font isn't one that Android Studio already provides so I used this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fB17m3kX-go
But I want to try to change the Typeface of the Toolbar title and there isn't a way to do so. I tried using setTextAppearance but I don't know how to use the styles.xml resources item to change it.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32398104/how-to-set-a-custom-font-to-the-title-in-toolbar-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a custom font to the title in toolbar android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32398104/how-to-set-a-custom-font-to-the-title-in-toolbar-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a `textview` inside toolbar in xml.
Then use `setTypeface()` to change typeface of that textview.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
     >
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your Title Here"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/title" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

The set typeface to `title`
In your Activity,

```
TextView toobar_title = findViewById(R.id.title);
toolbar_title.setTypeface(your_typeface);
```

Answer (score 1):

Paste the font file in `res/font` folder. 
If the `font` subfolder does not exist you have to create it, 
by right clicking on `res` and selecting `New>Android Resource Directory`, 
then set the name to `font`.  
In `styles.xml` create a theme for your toolbar:

```
<style name="MyToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/myfont</item>
</style>
```

and finally in your toolbar's xml add this attribute:

```
android:theme="@style/MyToolbarTheme"
```

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar is a view group. so you can put there any view you want. then you can modify those views as you want